# Problema com javascript filter em váriavel JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongodb, mongoose

Estou tentando capturar um determinado produto pelo seu `ID` utilizando o `filter` mas há alguns problemas. Está retornando apenas um array vazio.

Os produtos estão armazenados dentro de Categorias, ou seja, existe um array (`products`) destinado apenas para os produtos de cada categoria.

**Estrutura do JSON das Categorias**

```
[
    {
        "color": "blue",
        "_id": "5da5c64983f7162720710e81",
        "user_id": "5d9cc90b7120712fc4371f66",
        "name": "Bebida",
        "createdAt": "2019-10-15T13:14:49.748Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-10-28T21:14:31.816Z",
        "__v": 3,
        "products": [
            {
                "_id": "5db4da74316b5142042d3c42",
                "code": "2",
                "name": "Coca Cola 1L",
                "price": 7
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "color": "blue",
        "_id": "5db4e706f9400f41ccab9d66",
        "user_id": "5d9cc90b7120712fc4371f66",
        "name": "Lanche",
        "products": [
            {
                "_id": "5db4e71ff9400f41ccab9d67",
                "code": "3",
                "name": "X Salada",
                "price": 8
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2019-10-27T00:38:30.812Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-10-27T00:38:56.001Z",
        "__v": 1
    }
]
```

**Estrutura do JSON dos Produtos**

```
[
    [
        {
            "_id": "5db4da74316b5142042d3c42",
            "code": "2",
            "name": "Coca Cola 1L",
            "price": 7
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "_id": "5db4e71ff9400f41ccab9d67",
            "code": "3",
            "name": "X Salada",
            "price": 8
        }
    ]
]
```

**Código**

```
  async update(req, res){
    try{
      const { id, category_id } = req.params;
      const { code, name, description, price } = req.body;

      if (!id ||!category_id || !code || !name || (!price && price != 0))
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "Empty data" });

      // Capturando todas as categorias
      const categories = await Category.find({ user_id: req.user_id });

      if (!categories[0])
        return res.status(200).json({ success: false, message: "No categories found" });

      // Capturando apenas os produtos de todas as categorias
      const products = categories.map((_categories) => {
        return _categories.products;
      });

      // Capturando um produto pelo ID fornecido
      const product = products.filter((_product) => {
        if (_product._id == id)
          return _product;
      });

      return res.json(product);
    }catch(err){
      return res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: "System error" });
    }
  }
```

**Retorno**

```
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então Victor, está retornando vazio, pq deste jeito que fez vc não acessou toda a árvore do json para aplicar o **filter**:

```
const products = categories.map((_categories) => {
 return _categories.products;      // aqui existe um array envolvendo
});
```

Para acessar produtos vc precisa indicar o índice que envolve produtos, para depois acessá-lo e pegar o id:

```js
let dados = [
    {
        "color": "blue",
        "_id": "5da5c64983f7162720710e81",
        "user_id": "5d9cc90b7120712fc4371f66",
        "name": "Bebida",
        "createdAt": "2019-10-15T13:14:49.748Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-10-28T21:14:31.816Z",
        "__v": 3,
        "products": [
            {
                "_id": "5db4da74316b5142042d3c42",
                "code": "2",
                "name": "Coca Cola 1L",
                "price": 7
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "color": "blue",
        "_id": "5db4e706f9400f41ccab9d66",
        "user_id": "5d9cc90b7120712fc4371f66",
        "name": "Lanche",
        "products": [
            {
                "_id": "5db4e71ff9400f41ccab9d67",
                "code": "3",
                "name": "X Salada",
                "price": 8
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2019-10-27T00:38:30.812Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-10-27T00:38:56.001Z",
        "__v": 1
    }
]

let retorno = dados
              .map(_product => _product.products[0])
              .filter(x => x._id == '5db4da74316b5142042d3c42'); // aqui vai o id

console.log(retorno);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ele ta retornando um Array [] porque o método filter se ele não encontra o que você quer encontrar, ele vai retornar sempre um array vazio. Então talvez ele não esteja encontrando o ID que você queira. Um link pra te ajudar: [Método Filter Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

E uma dica, talvez você poderia usar esta biblioteca que ele gera um ID automaticamente: [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4)

Comment: Talvez fosse melhor transformar esse texto em um comentário anexado a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Vitor como products é um array e provavelmente terá vários registros dentro de uma mesma categoria, se vc passar o index como o LeAndrade falou, vc pode ter erros, tenta fazer assim:

```
let dados.find((categorie) => categorie.name === 'Bebida')
         .products.find((product) => product._id === '5db4da74316b5142042d3c42');
console.log(res);
```

usando o .find() diferente do .filter()/.map() o retorno é o elememto em si e não um array.